# How do I use keras NN to classify data after training?

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, keras, tensorflow

I have defined, trained and saved my tensor keras NN. Now that that is complete how do I use it output classifications to non training data?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from syslog import syslog_pred

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 8 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.load_weights('.my_model')

x = np.array([arr[:-1] for arr in syslog_pred], dtype=np.float32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)

answer = model.predict(dataset, steps=30)
print(answer)
```

The code at the end isn't what it should be but I'm a little lost.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a trained model, you can pass new samples to it by using the `predict` method of the model, which will get you the probabilities of all classes. You than pick the class with the highest probability for each sample as the predicted class:

```
y_prob = model.predict(new_data)   # Get class probability vector for each sample
y_class = y_prob.argmax(axis=-1)   # Set prediction to class with highest probability
```

If you are using a `Sequential()` model, you can also use the `predict_classes` method, which will get you the same answer:

```
y_class = model.predict_classes(new_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

To predict classes you simply need:

```
answer = model.predict_classes(dataset)
```